# C# ASP.NET read first bytes of body without buffering full body

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET API that receives a file from a request. I'm interested in reading the first few bytes for validation. I know that I can set `HttpRequest.EnableBuffering()` which allows me to read the first bytes and reset the position back of the Stream. But after that the stream will be written to disk/buffered once it is fully read by an external method.

I was wondering if I can extract the first few bytes without buffering the full request. I have tried is creating a new class that inherits from `Stream` and 'intercepts' the buffer in the read methods to perform the validation. It feels a bit finicky though.

Controller action

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
{
    //required to enable Seek on Stream
    Request.EnableBuffering();
    if (!await MyValidator.IsValidAsync(Request.Body)) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    //external SDK that reads entire Stream
    await client.ProcessFileAsync(Request.Body);
    return StatusCode(201, id);
}
```

Validating file format:

```cs
public static class MyValidator
{
    public static async Task<bool> IsValidAsync(Stream stream)
    {
        if (!stream.CanSeek)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        var pos = stream.Position;
        var array = new byte[4];
        await stream.ReadAsync(array, 0, array.Length);
        stream.Seek(pos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return array.SequenceEqual(new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF });
    }
}
```

Current idea:

```
public class InterceptorStream : Stream
{
    private readonly Stream Stream;
    private bool Validated;

    public InterceptorStream(Stream stream)
    {
        Stream = stream;
    }

    public override async Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await Stream.ReadAsync(buffer.AsMemory(offset, count), cancellationToken);
        if (!Validated)
        {
            //potential of validation being skipped
            if (result >= 4)
            {
                var prefix = buffer[..4].ToArray();
                if (!prefix.SequenceEqual(new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF }))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Stream is not a valid file format");
                }
            }
            Validated = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    //rest of the implementation
}
```

Comment: Do you want to intercept the first few bytes in a middleware?

Comment: @PeterCsala no; it can be in the controller action.

Comment: I'm asking it because if you want to read it only once then you don't need to enable buffering. So, if you read the first n bytes and your validation logic fails then you can simply reject the request. Otherwise you read the remaining bytes from the stream.

Comment: Yes, but if those bytes are valid the stream will no longer read the first few bytes necessary once I pass the stream to the external method. If I enable buffering after validation it'll still buffer the entire file when it's being read by the external method.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I can follow the data flow. Can you please share with us some code to see how the stream is read and passed around?

Comment: @PeterCsala added code

Comment: Thanks, now the data flow make sense. You want to perform a preliminary check prior passing the stream to an external lib for further processing. Does the external lib requires the first n bytes as well? If not, then you just don't need to call the `Seek` inside your `IsValidAsync`.

Comment: Yes; the full stream is required. In the basics it can be considered a download of the file.

Comment: If you need that whole stream then you have to enabled buffering. I'm unaware of any other option.

Comment: Doing the validation in the InterceptorStream is a good idea. Then throw a custom exception that is managed in the controller's action. Just `if(offset == 0 ...` sound incorrect. Maybe `if(Stream.Position == 0 ...`?

Comment: Thanks. @vernou you are correct. It should be `Position`. Snippet was from quick test but will correct it in case somebody copy pastes it.

Comment: I would create a separate `PostValidator()` action method, that only reads and sends the "few bytes".